# Image is not Displaying properly?

Tags: formula, lookup, tab, images

I have used this formula to show different image based on stages.

```
CASE(Stage__c, 
"S1" , IMAGE("resource/1386053185000/StageColorPink", "pink",15,15) , 
"S2" , IMAGE("resource/1386053058000/StageColorlightBlue", "lightBlue",15,15), 
"S3" , IMAGE("resource/1386052789000/StageColorBlue", "blue",15,15), 
"S4" , IMAGE("resource/1386051242000/StageColorGreen", "Green",15,15), 
"S5" , IMAGE("resource/1386052820000/StageColorYellow", "yellow",15,15), 
"S6" , IMAGE("resource/1386052658000/StageColorRed", "Red",15,15), 
"" 
)
```

[image]
 Images will be displayed properly if i am in "List View(Attached Image)" OR "Record Page", when I include the same fields either in Tab view OR Look Up fields Images will be Broken. How to resolve this Issue ?

This is Tab View 
[image]

Comment: Your tab view screen shot looks like you are displaying a column of checkboxes i.e some field other than "stage Color"... But assuming you are not, I suggest you use your browser's "Inspect Element" feature to compare the HTML rendered in the working and non working cases to get some idea of what is going on.

Comment: Those are not Checkboxes, those are Images which are not displaying properly

Comment: I Inspected the Element in both Cases in "List View" Image URL is "https://ap1.salesforce.com/resource/1386052658000/StageColorRed"  in Tab View Image URl is "https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0g/resource/1386052789000/StageColorRed" .....What is "a0g" in Tab view URL ???

Comment: The list view of a type is displayed by entering '/xxx' where 'xxx' is the first 3 digits of an id for that type. See what '/a0g' displays in your org - probably a list of one of your custom objects. But how to avoid this problem (or whether it is avoidable at all) in formulas I don't know...

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute URL i.e. starting with '/resource'?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your formula to be:

```
CASE(Stage__c, 
"S1" , IMAGE("/resource/1386053185000/StageColorPink", "pink",15,15) , 
"S2" , IMAGE("/resource/1386053058000/StageColorlightBlue", "lightBlue",15,15), 
"S3" , IMAGE("/resource/1386052789000/StageColorBlue", "blue",15,15), 
"S4" , IMAGE("/resource/1386051242000/StageColorGreen", "Green",15,15), 
"S5" , IMAGE("/resource/1386052820000/StageColorYellow", "yellow",15,15), 
"S6" , IMAGE("/resource/1386052658000/StageColorRed", "Red",15,15), 
"" 
)
```

The difference is that I added a leading forward slash in front of each image link.

In your previous formula you were using the link:

```
resource/1386053185000/StageColorPink
```

This will get appended to the subfolder you are in. If you were visiting a detail page such as `https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0g000000000000` it was working because there is no subfolder and the link will point to `https://ap1.salesforce.com/resource/1386053185000/StageColorPink`

However, if you look at the overview page for your custom object, `https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0g/o`, you'll notice that there is a subfolder, `a0g`. This results in the image pointing to `https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0g/resource/1386053185000/StageColorPink` which does not exist.

To fix this, we can prepend the link with `/`, to force the link to always start with the root directory. This makes the link `https://ap1.salesforce.com/resource/1386053185000/StageColorPink` in both cases.

See also this question on stackoverflow: [Why would a developer place a forward slash at the start of each relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path)